# What can be the reason notebook does not load with PXE?

Tags: pxe, syslinux, netboot, tftpd

I made TFTP boot share and it works for virtual machine and desktop computer (menu appears). But on notebook Dell Inspiron 7720 it shows few lines

[image]

and turns black.

Syslinux config is follows:

```
$ cat pxelinux.cfg/default
DEFAULT menu.c32
PROMPT 0
#MENU BACKGROUND moon800.jpg
#MENU RESOLUTION 800 600
#MENU MARGIN 20

MENU TITLE In The Moon Network

LABEL kaspersky
MENU LABEL Kaspersky Rescue Disk (WAIT!)
KERNEL memdisk
INITRD /iso/kav_rescue_10.iso
APPEND harddisk raw

LABEL rescue
MENU LABEL SystemRescueCd x86 4.7.1 (WAIT!)
KERNEL memdisk
INITRD /iso/systemrescuecd-x86-4.7.1.iso
APPEND iso raw

LABEL ubuntudesktop
MENU LABEL Run Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.1 LTS (WAIT!)
KERNEL memdisk
INITRD http://sagittarius-a/boot/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso
APPEND harddisk raw

LABEL ubuntu-installer-amd64-desktop-16.04-lts
MENU LABEL Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop AMD64
KERNEL ubuntu-installer/16.04LTS/amd64/boot-screens/vesamenu.c32
APPEND ubuntu-installer/16.04LTS/amd64/boot-screens/menu.cfg
```

Content of TFTP directory is follows:

```
/var/lib/tftpboot$ ls
iso           libutil.c32  menu.c32     netboot            ubuntu-installer
ldlinux.c32   lpxelinux.0  moon640.jpg  pxelinux.cfg       vesamenu.c32
libcom32.c32  memdisk      moon800.jpg  sagittarius-a.jpg
```

The problem it doesn't show any menu at all.

**UPDATE**

I have replaced `lpxelinux.0` for `pxelinux.0` and revised all `c32` to have them from single distribution of syslinux, but finally got the same result.

Why is it loading `NBP` file several (two) times?